# How to open a rich:tooltip when mouse is moving over specific area of content?

Tags: javascript, jsf, dom-events, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 4.3.4 and Jsf 2.2.1 and
I have a `rich:panenMenu` nested in a `rich:toolTip`.

Is there any possibility to show the tooltip when I move the mouse on the left side of my content page? There should be an area of ~10% of the width of the left side, where the tooltip gets opened and the user can access the Menu.

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip needs to be attached to an element. Put a div where you want the tooltip to show and then set @target of the tooltip to the div's id.

On the other hand, why not use `<rich:contextMenu>` instead? Tooltip is meant for displaying tooltips.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. I chose the tooltip with panelMenu because the contextMenu does not have the property "activeItem" to leave a selected menuGroup expanded. Is there a way to accomplish this with rich:ContextMenu?